# Find the set of real numbers $u$ such that $u/(u−1) ≤ 2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, real-numbers

Find the set of real numbers $u$ such that 
$u/(u−1) ≤ 2$.

I don't really know how to get started with this.

Comment: Consider two cases: $u-1<0$ and $u-1>0$. Multiply by $(u-1)$ in each case, handling the inequality sign carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get an easier *feel* make the substitution $u=t+1$ so we require $1+\frac1{t} \le 2$ or 
$$
\frac1{t} \le 1
$$
clearly any $t \lt 0$ will do. if $t\gt 0$ then we have $1 \le t$

so the required interval for $t$ is $\mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1)$

since $u=t+1$ the required interval for $u$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus [1,2)$

the status of the singularity is a slightly more delicate question

Comment: Is the interval negative or is that  a dash?

Comment: sorry, typo! meant "setminus"

Answer (score 0):

we rewrite as $$ 2-\frac{u}{u-1}=\frac{2u-2-u}{u-1}=\frac{u-2}{u-1}$$ thus we obtain $$u\geq 2$$ or $$u<1$$